# JPA Using Composite Fields To Store Multiple @Column On An @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a **user** table and I am using Hibernate to read it into **User** instances. I want to collect a number of related columns under a **composite** object to pass it around. So, I want to do something like this:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    // A bunch of columns
    ...

    private Statistics stats;
}
```

Now I want to read some of the columns in the same **user** table into the fields in my Statistics object.

```
public class Statistics {

    @Column
    private int x;

    @Column
    private int y;

    // A bunch of columns
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to achieve that? I don't prefer to use a separate table for statistics and use joins because of some performance concerns. I can obviously move the fields from the Statistics class into the User class but I want to improve the design by using composite objects.

Comment: so you basically want to take the subset of the `User` columns to operate on in Java code, right?

Comment: Sure, I want to take a subset of columns and pack it into another struct under User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for @Embeddable and @Embedded annotations.

As I remember from top of my head, it should be something like:

```
@Embeddable
public class PhoneNumber{
}

@Entity
public class Customer
{
    @Embedded
    private PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
}
```